# How can I get my images to appear in my Netlify website? (sveltekit app)

Tags: image, svelte, netlify, sveltekit

I created a repo using sveltekit and successfully deployed it with Netlify, however the images will not load, their 'alt' attribute is all that shows up as seen in the image.

If I run the project locally using 'npm run dev' the images DO appear fine.

[image: images not showing up]

Here is the code where I have the img tags:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="/src/images/github.png" alt=GitHub></a></li> 
    <li><img src="/src/images/linkedin.png" alt=LinkedIn></a></li>
    <li><img src="/src/images/email.png" alt=Email></a></li>
</ul>
```

Do I need to edit the paths somehow? Or maybe something in my svelte.config.js file:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-netlify';
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),
    }
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very sure but SSR of sveltekit might be a problem in this case (Try vercel they seem to have better SSR support)! And yeah try putting your images in static folder .

Comment: adding them to the static folder worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Put your image to this site `https://cloudinary.com` and get the link of the image and then try to use the link in src this will help you from the error.